# Descargar base de datos en forma horizontal con PHP

Tags: php, mysql, excel, csv

Muy buenas a tod@s, les vengo a solicitar de su valiosa ayuda en este ultimo dia del año.
Tengo un proyecto en CorelDraw y estoy probando la opcion de importar los datos desde la base de datos. (en cierta parte ha sido facil, en el resto no, se los explico a continuacion)
El proyecto es para hacer Diplomas (en tamaño normal y otros en tamano ID)
tengo la tabla de estudiantes
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo para descargar el archivo de registros es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y obtengo el resultado siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

hasta aqui, todo bien, nada del otro mundo, el problema para mi es el siguiente:

1. Tengo que descargarlo en formato *.rtf
2. tengo que descargar un segundo archivo (en el mismo formato *.rtf), pero, de forma vertical, osea asi:
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando dice hasta 8, quiero decir que me muestre los primeros 8 registros (del 0-7, 8-15, etc)
el bucle tiene que ser de 8 registros, ya que son los que caben por pagina en el caso del tamano ID, como hacer la paginacion.
No se si me explique bien o no.
Si alguien me puede y quiere ayudar, se lo agradecere muchisimo.

Comment: son millones de registros?? cual es el problema para hacer una macro e ir escribiendo lo que queres en el mismo excel?? tampoco entiendo porque estando en mysql, tuviste que escribir un programa para algo que la db hace automaticamente (exportar esta en cualquier manejador de DB)

Comment: Dentro de tu ciclo lleva un contador, y cuando sea el 8vo alumno agrega "\n". Asumo que ya investigaste sobre [rtf](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format).

Comment: No, no son millones de registros, pero, por si no entendio, esa informacion la estoy llamando desde el programa que guarda en la base de datos la informacion de cada alumno, asi que, Cual seria la gracia de hacer todo manual desde Excel o desde MySQL, si para ello "programo" un boton que haga lo que quiero.
Ya con el resultado de guardar los registros en formato *.rtf (como lo solicita CorelDraw), se vuelve mas practico el trabajo, espero haber respondido su duda mi amigo, gbianchi.
Feliz año nuevo y gracias por tomarse el tiempo en responder.